# How to get the intersection between the scatterred points and the circle?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image: Matlab plot]

I'm using canny edge detection to detect the edges of a rope and eliminate the background, then using morphological filters I'm filling these edges then thinning them to be in pixel size. The plot indicates the xy coordinates of the rope. What I need to do is to get the intersection of the scattered data (blue *) with the red circle (get the coordinates of Points (1,2,3,4).

Then I need to get the whole points coordinates from the point of intersection (point1,2,3,4) to the center,grouped as A,B,C,D.

The center of the circle, the origin of the axes, and the radius are all known.

I've tried some Matlab functions to get the four intersections points like

> InterX,intersections

and also I tried to manually find the intersections

```
idx=find(y1-y2<eps);
```

but no method gives me the 4 intersection points.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: minimal example...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a thick circle. I presume (from your previous question) that the rope points are at contiguous integer coordinates. Using a thick circle (donut) with a width of 1 ensures you'll find at least one point in each rope end. Connected component analysis will then tell you which of these points belong to the same rope end.